# How to access contact name and custom field from detail record?

Tags: apex, soql, master-detail

Assuming that Training__c  is the child of contact in a master/detail relationship how to fix my WHERE so that it works? Right now I get an error "Didn't understand relationship 'contact__r' in field path..."

```
Select Name, Start_Date__c,Start_Time__c,End_Time__c,Trainer__c
                    FROM Training__c 
                    WHERE contact__r.name like '%community%' AND contact__r.Active_Candidate__c = True
                    ORDER BY Start_Date__c,Start_Time__c
```

Comment: what is the API name of this M-D field?

Comment: There should be a field on Training__c that contains the Id of the contact record of it's parent that you can reference to establish the relationship to get the parent fields. You can also use Parent-Child query notation to do the query but it's easier if you have the field name.

Comment: This answered my question. Make it an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make sure you find the `API Name` of the relationship field.

1. Go to `Setup` > `Create` > `Objects`.
2. Select your `Custom Object`.
3. Look at the `Custom Fields & Relationships` section and find the `API Name`.
4. You can programmatically verify the relationship name as shown below:

Execute Anonymous:

```
system.debug(MyObject__c.ContactRelationship__c.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());
```

This process will give you the cross-object reference to use in your queries in place of `Contact__r`.

Comment: @Apex Did this answer not resolve your issue?